# iOS - automatically open app from background

Tags: ios

Is it possible to reopen the app from background mode in some way?
For example, if the app in background is checking the server for some flag, and then when triggered, it will automatically go to foreground?

If not, can i display a message and play sound for the user to request app reopen?

How does for example WhatsApp achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to automatically *open* the app, meaning display the app to the user.

However it is possible using Push Notifications to have your app opened in the background so that it can perform a short task. This is achieved by creating a [push notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW57) with the `content-available` field.

> If your server sends push notifications to a user’s device when new content is available for your app, you can ask the system to run your app in the background so that it can begin downloading the new content right away. The intent of this background mode is to minimize the amount of time that elapses between when a user sees a push notification and when your app is able to able to display the associated content. Apps are typically woken up at roughly the same time that the user sees the notification but that still gives you more time than you might have otherwise.
>
> To support this background mode, enable the Remote notifications option from the Background modes section of the Capabilities tab in your Xcode project. (You can also enable this support by including the `UIBackgroundModes` key with the `remote-notification` value in your app’s `Info.plist` file.)
>
> For a push notification to trigger a download operation, the notification’s payload must include the content-available key with its value set to 1. When that key is present, the system wakes the app in the background (or launches it into the background) and calls the app delegate’s [application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) method. Your implementation of that method should download the relevant content and integrate it into your app.
>
> When downloading any content, it is recommended that you use the [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLSession) class to initiate and manage your downloads. For information about how to use this class to manage upload and download tasks, see *[URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i)*.

---

> can i display a message and play sound for the user to request app reopen?

Yes, you can just use a [Local Notification or a Push Notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html)

Comment: If we assume app is installed on the device, but never opened (so communication with APNs was never established, thus no push notifications are possible to happen) - can anything cause app to start (in background) other than explicit opening the app by the user (or some other way that causes app to open and actually come to foreground)?

Comment: @uerceg, No, I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple when app in background all function will pause automatically and will resume when app in activate again.The only thing you can do local notification with badge or sound please read this  documentation  for more information [Notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

> if the app in background is checking the server for some flag, and
>   then when triggered, it will automatically go to foreground?

Not possible as of now.

> can i display a message and play sound for the user to request app 
>   reopen?

Yes. When you dispatch the Local notification, an alert would pop up on the user's screen. Sample code for adding a local notification:

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.alertBody = @"AlertBody";
localNotification.alertAction = @"AlertAction";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];    
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

When application is opened by tapping on the notification, following parameter 'launchOptions' will get the value:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Debug and find the value for launchOptions:

```
    [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
```