# How can I open pop up ViewController in background mode - iOS

Tags: swift, popup, ibeacon, background-mode

the app in background mode. when detect Ibeacon(https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/) in background mode open popup.

I can display local-notification to the user when detect Ibeacon detect.

Is Apple allows to open popup in background-mode Swift?

lang - Swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible as you need a `ViewController` or a `NavigationController` to show the `AlertController` from.

Also, it is not possible to show a `ViewController` from a background mode.

By now, your only option is to show `LocalNotification` or `PushNotification` and trigger the APP when the users clicks on it.

Check also this other [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32249843/2633085)