# How to launch the app when I get Remote message from pusher in background state

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, pusher

This is my code for getting a remote message from the pusher.

```
self.pusher = [PTPusher pusherWithKey:@"pusherKey" delegate:self encrypted:YES cluster:@"ap2"];
PTPusherChannel *channel = [self.pusher subscribeToChannelNamed:@"my-channel"];

[channel bindToEventNamed:@"my-event" handleWithBlock:^(PTPusherEvent *channelEvent) {
    NSString *message = [channelEvent.data objectForKey:@"message"];
    }];

[self.pusher connect];
```

Comment: please refer...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393673/detect-if-the-app-was-launched-opened-from-a-push-notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to launch app automatically when in the background.
Performing some short task is available but not launch app.

Comment: Now I got remote message using UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier when app is in bakground.

Comment: @LeninS what you want to achieve ,Did my answer confuse you ?

Comment: I want to open the app when I get the remote message.

Comment: As my answer mentioned, it is not available . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32249797/ios-automatically-open-app-from-background

Comment: Thanks for your answer Cole Xia. I have used a local notification there. And I need to know is there any way to open the app without tapping that notification.

Comment: @LeninS No, you must tap the notification if you are going to open the app.    Other ways to open the app is tapping the  App extention , link:https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/    and  use custom url scheme,link:http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

Comment: Thanks Brother. Now I am looking for getting remote message when app is terminated.