# Is it possible to launch the application silently on background after the app upgrade

Tags: ios, swift

In iOS, is it possible to execute some tasks right after the app got upgraded? I want these tasks to be executed even if the user is not opening the app after the app upgrade.
Is it possible to launch the application silently on background after the app upgrade

For example, sending an analytics event right after the app upgrade, without the need of launching the application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS - automatically open app from background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32249797/ios-automatically-open-app-from-background)

Comment: @Aswathy you need to update the question with what is the purpose of sending the analytics event right after the app update? So I am just assuming you want to cover the adoption trend and don't want to miss the segment where the users update their app but don't open the app[Technically its of no use as you can still consider this segment is not updated as they are not yet using the new app!], ok now if you still want to get that stat then [App Analytics](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/measuring-app-performance/) is the place to look for more details.

Answer (score 2):

In short - No.

You can try and use different background capabilities Apple supplies to wake up your application in the background and check if an upgrade took place. There are no known triggers (at the time of writing this post April 2023) to wake up the application when an upgrade takes place.

Some background capabilities for you to explore (they all require special permissions from the user, and could affect the user experience):

1. [Silent Push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app).

- Note that there are no guarantees for this API and try not to abuse it, as there is a limit on the number of silent push you can send to your application before the OS/Apple will start throttling them.

2. [Background tasks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks)

A full list of the background modes is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-background-execution-modes)

Comment: When we update the app via Appstore how does our BE service which is out of the Apple echo system will get to know to send silent push notification? IMO without opening the app explicitly by the user there is no way to do any operation which is specific to handle post update scenario.

Comment: As I said you have no way to achieve that. What I have suggested is to **schedule** one or two (let's say on the user timezone, morning and noon) silent push to wake up the app in the background - check if there was an upgrade -> then send the analytic event. It is a wasteful technique